# Detect Web App browsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I have a website and i use that also as web app built with Thunkable. Just to make it clear for those that don't use Thunkable, i just put my website in a web-viewer and create an App with that. But actually my App works simply as my website in all aspects.

When i detect an Android visitor in my **mobile website**

```
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
```

i promote my App through an alert box

```
window.confirm("sometext");
```

This happens also in my Web App since my App just shows a view of my mobile website framed as App.

My question is: Is there any way to detect a visitor from my Web App so i not show box alert to them since they have already installed my App?

I'm working with Thunkable to build my App so the only solution would be coding my website and not App coding.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From Thunkable, you can set Some flag before opening up the page and then from page you can check if that flag is there or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not a solution. I can already detect my Android visitors. I want to detect visitors visiting from my App (Web app with my website view on it)  on Android so i not show to them my alert.

Comment: It's fine, you don't show them alert, but on android it uses native chrome, and this code will detect if it;s android or not, can you make it more clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: I explained a little bit better how Thunkable works. people visiting my app receive the same data as visiting my mobile website. the difference in my app is that they go through a web viewer offered by Thunkable. So in both cases they are served native chrome and they receive the alert in this case. What i want is a code making the difference between an Android simple mobile website visit and  Android app visit so i don't show to the app visit my alert. Thank you